# html pattern to only accept numbers

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have this simple html:

```
<input type="text" 
       placeholder="onlynumbers" 
       name="onlynumbers" 
       pattern="\d{1,5}"  
       maxlength="5">
```

I need to restrict the number of characters to 5. It works. But I still can type other characters than numbers.
I have tried various pattern, for example:

```
pattern = "[0-9]"
```

But it is still possible to type other characters than digits.

If I change the `type` attribute to `number`, then only digits are accepted in the input field but the `maxlength` attribute doesn't work. I can enter as many digits as I want. I heard this was a bug in Chrome. Is that the problem?

Is there a cross-browser way to fulfil these requirements:

*An input field (text or number, no matters) that only accept digits and doesn't let the user enter more than 5 digits.*

Comment: `pattern` does not prevent the user from entering other characters. To prevent, you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: The correct attributes for a number input are min & max. Use `max="99999"` Also the pattern attribute is implicitly a whole string match. So `pattern="[0-9]"` means "only one digit"

Comment: Please [**search thoroughly**](/search?q=input+accept+only+numbers) before posting. More on searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: use `type='number'` in `input` element

Comment: `<input type="number">` may be?

Answer (score 31):

```
<input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="[0-9]+" title="please enter number only" required="required">
```

Comment: This is the right answer. `type="number"` is for amounts. That's why most browsers display spinner controls. If you're asking for i.e. a house number, it's not an amount, you just expect numbers.

Comment: Another use case where type="text" is needed.: the number is an identifier and may start with a "0".

Comment: actually better would be use  type="tel" as from mozilla docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel

Answer (score 10):

Use `max` instead of `maxlength` with `input type="number"`. For example, to specify max length of 5 digits, use

```
<input type="number" max="99999" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Below jQuery code to check with regex (For old browsers that does not support the type=number input pattern)

```js
$(function(){
  $("input[name='onlynumbers']").on('input', function (e) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="onlynumbers" name="onlynumbers"   maxlength="5">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This Code snippets to restrict input to only 5 digits and  restrict to letters with the help of JavaScript make thing easier instead of JQuery

```js
function isNumber(evt)
   {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Restrict Number</title>
 <script src="number.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
 Number:<input type="text" maxlength="5" onkeypress=" return isNumber(event)"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

Why not you use number input type?

```html
<input type="number" name="onluNumbers" min="1" max="99999">
```

Comment: because sometimes you need the output to be string, that means leading zeros are important

Comment: @Johan idk about you...  but `theInput.value` *does* seem to be a string (retaining all leading zeros too)